# Mongoose - post update can't access this

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i'm using mongoose, and middle ware, when i try to access this._id in any of the models is undefined

```
ClientSchema.post('update', function() {
  console.log(this._id);
});
```

any ideas why ?

My Schema

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    company: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'}
});
ClientSchema.post('save', function() {
  console.log(this._id); ///working
});
ClientSchema.post('update', function() {
  console.log(this._id); ///undefined
});
```

Comment: What is ClientSchema and does it have a post method?

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo edited

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ClientSchema.post('update', function() {
   const document = this.getUpdate();
   console.log(document.id); ///working
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The result should be passed as a parameter to the callback function like this

```
ClientSchema.post('update', function(res) {
  console.log(res._id);
});
```

You could also uses promises, that way you can catch errors that might occur

```
ClientSchema.post('update').then(function(res) {
   console.log(res._id)
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: still undefined

Comment: edited @JenuRudan You can see errors so as to know how to better debug

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3051

Should work:

```
ClientSchema.post('update', function(client) {
   console.log(client._id);
});
```

Comment: Client.update({_id: id}, updatedAttributes, function (err) {

                    if (err) {
                        res.json({status: false, error: err});
                        return;
                    }
                    res.json({status: true, message: 'Client Updated'});

                });